# How to fix vertical text frame size (including footnotes)?

Tags: lyx, footnotes, paper-size

I'm using LyX to typeset a document, and get a predictable page size when no footnotes are around. However, when I use footnotes, those are added as **extra** at the bottom of the page, changing the overall size of the 'text frame' of the document. In my case, it's critical to keep the maximum frame consistent so that e-readers such as KDX would show them uniformly without text shrinking. So my question - is there any way to tell LaTeX/LyX to do this?

Just to give an analogy, in InDesign you define a text frame and that's where *everything* goes - text *and* footnotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are willing to use the [geometry](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/geometry) package, you could load it with the options `includefoot` (and `includehead`, if necessary) to inform LaTeX that the dimensions of the textblock should include the footer (and header, if necessary).

Comment: Thanks, can you elaborate on how I would set this up under LyX? I assume I need to add something to the custom header...

Comment: Just include the instruction `\usepackage[includefoot,includehead]{geometry}` in the document's preamble.

Comment: Interesting - when I add this statement, I get a completely different frame size. Do I have to redefine it now?

Comment: The answer is going to depend importantly on your paper and textblock dimensions, about which you haven't told us much so far. Please check out the manual of the `geometry` package -- there's a link to it in the answer I provided initially -- for information on setting the horizontal and vertical margins.